# Yii - Including the Jquery and bootstrap js in the end

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am working in Yii and using **YiiBooster** and the standard **Jquery** that is included with Yii. Whenever I open a page, I see that the JS files have been added in the top (head) of the page. I don't want to do this. I want them to be included in the end. Before the end of the body tag.

How do I do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default vaue of `Yii::app()->clientScript->coreScriptPosition` is `CClientScript::POS_HEAD`

You can overwrite it by

```
public $coreScriptPosition = CClientScript::POS_END;
```

or include in application's config as

```
'components' => [
...
    'clientScript' => [
        'coreScriptPosition' => CClientScript::POS_END
    ],
```

or you can open the `Bootstrap.php` file on your bootstrap/component folder, search the function registerCoreScripts() and modify it like this

```
public function registerCoreScripts()
    {
        //$this->registerJS(Yii::app()->clientScript->coreScriptPosition); //OLD
        $this->registerJS(CClientScript::POS_END); // modified
        $this->registerPopover(); // popover also registers tooltip
    }
```